# word to replace " interest "

Tags: word-choice

I applied for a job position last year, and I want to continue to apply for it this year. Then I say, "My interest doesn't change", but I think "interest" is a little bit weak in this case, and "passion" makes the tone too strong. 
What is the best word to replace the "interest" in this case?

Comment: Can you give us the whole sentence? Based on the snippet you've given us, the grammar doesn't look quite correct

Comment: "My interest doesn't change" is poorly constructed, unless the context is different from what I'm envisioning.  What @SGR said.

Answer (score 1):

My interest in the position remains undiminished.

http://www.learnersdictionary.com/definition/undiminished

"She continued to work with undiminished enthusiasm.

His interest in the project remains undiminished."

Comment: Yes, it seems "enthusiasm" is good. Could I say "my enthusiasm" become much more stronger?

Comment: First of all, you can't say much more stronger, much stronger would be the expression, but I'm not sure if it would be appropriate to say your enthusiasm for the position is much stronger a year after you first applied. It might be more realistic to convey that your enthusiasm is as strong today as it was when you first applied. In addition, interest might be more appropriate than enthusiasm, since you haven't been hired yet. If you want to use the word strong, you could say: My interest in the position is as strong as ever. This expression isn't as formal as 'remains undiminished'.

Answer (score 0):

Since it is hard to find an alternative for "interest" that is not clearly stronger (fascination? excitement?), why not modify the verb?

E.g. "My interest in the job has not diminished." If your interest is really strong, you might write, "My excitement about the job has not diminished" (or "decreased").

Answer (score -1):

I think in the context of this case the word `curiosity` stands out. Google's definitions of both `curiosity` and `interesting`:

> Interesting: arousing curiosity or interest; holding or catching the attention.
>
> Curiosity: a strong desire to know or learn something.

You seem to have an interest in the position position you're applying for, which implies you're curious about what it would be like to be in that position.

Curiosity shows you want the position and you're enthusiastic about being in that position, but it doesn't come on as you being over zealous.